# What's the JSX and what is it really doing in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I really need to know what JSX is and what it's really doing in my below React code.

This is my react code which I coded in `src/index.js` file.

```
const greetDate = () => {
    const getDate = new Date();
    return getDate.toDateString();
}

const greeting = <h1> Hello World. Now current time is {greetDate()}.</h1>
ReactDOM.render(greeting, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is JSX?** The answer is **[here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)**

Summarizing from the official doc:

...JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with the full power of JavaScript. ...**JSX produces React “elements”.**

This piece of code is not jsx:

```
const greetDate = () => {
    const getDate = new Date();
    return getDate.toDateString();
}
```

The previous code is just javascript **ES6** syntax.

This is jsx:

```
const greeting = <h1> Hello World. Now current time is {greetDate()}.</h1>
ReactDOM.render(greeting, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And will be transpiled to:

```
var greeting = React.createElement(
    'h1',
    null,
    ' Hello World. Now current time is ',
    greetDate(),
    '.'
);
ReactDOM.render(greeting, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Go to **BabelJS**, and paste your code in the left panel, you will see the result in the right: https://babeljs.io/en/repl